# Costs Related to Individual Bucket Items in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My AWS S3 costs have been going up pretty quickly for usage type "DataTransfer-Out-Bytes". I have thousands of images in this one bucket and I can't seem to find a way to drill down into the bucket to see which individual bucket items might be causing the increase. Is there a way to see which individual files are attributing to the higher data transfer cost?

Comment: See [Logging options for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/logging-with-S3.html).

Comment: You can try to use that tool http://img.blogabond.com/cfstats/usage_201007.html#TOPENTRY as well, but the first comment also fine

Comment: I don't know the scenario but you might want to consider caching the items in cloudfront if it is a public facing thing

Answer (score 0):

Use Cloudfront if you can - its cheaper(*if* you properly set your cache headers!) than directly hosting from S3 and Cloudfront includes a [popular objects report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/popular-objects-report.html) -  which would answer your question.

If your using S3 alone you need to [enable logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html) on the bucket (more storage cost) and then crunch the data in the logs (more data transfer cost) to get your answer. You can use [AWS Athena to process the s3 access logs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/) or use unix command line tools like grep/wc/uniq/cut to operate on the log files locally/from a server to find the culprits.